# Why is the number of distinct labelings on n vertices the sum of the possible labelings of unlabeled trees on n vertices?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, trees

First of all, is this true? Since there is no closed formula for the number of unlabeled trees on n vertices it is not something I know how to prove using, for instance, induction. (This is an observation I made when writing out a few problems, but I'm not 100% sure if I can just assume it or there is something that needs to be proved first).

Might be a little bit of a naive question, but I am wondering if there is a combinatorial/intuitive explanation to this sort of question? Or is it something that follows trivially from the definition? That is, if we take the unlabeled trees on $n$ vertices and find the labelings for each one and then take the sum, it will basically give us Cayley's formula of distinct labelings on $n$ vertices.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I don't understand what the "sum of the possible labelings of unlabeled trees" is.  Perhaps you could give an example for some small $n$.

Comment: @saulspatz Sure, https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Tree.html, if we look at n = 4 there are 2 unlabeled trees, each one has a possible number of labelings, for the first one there are 4 possible labelings and for the second one there are 12 possible labelings. If we add them up we get 16, which is $4^{4-2}$.

Comment: But then isn't it clear?  Every labeled tree is a labeling of an unlabeled tree.  Look at the diagram of  $n=4$ case in the article on [Cayley's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%27s_formula)